# How to export exact format table from teradata to excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, teradata, xlsxwriter

For a project at work, i need to export from teradata to excel an sql request.

So far i managed to fully export several request to my excel file, but the output format is not exactly what I am looking for. Indeed the output does not respect the origin table and just gave a concatenation row by row like :
        A
1('000000000DUM', 'RRFOR', '', '', 'NOTE_CONTREP', '20.00')
and i want

A1 :000000000DUM           B1 : RRFOR     C1 :''    D1 : ''      E1 : NOTE_CONTREP             F1 :  20.00

This is my code :

```
def KPI_MAKER(instid):
conn=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Teradata};DBCNAME=FTGPRDTD;UID='+str('L291506')+';PWD='+str('Pilote06!')+';QUIETMODE=YES;')
Agg=str("sel code_gen1,code_gen2,cd_prd_cpta,lieu_stkph_cd,don_source_cd,incorrect_value from DB_FTG_SRS_DATALAB.mdc_ctrl_anomalie where rg_no = 'RGC-TIE-012'")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(Agg)
Agg_output = cursor.fetchall()
conn.close

df = pd.DataFrame(Agg_output)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('KPI_FORTIS_13082019.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='POC_output')    # sheet 0
writer.save()
print('done')
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `fetchall` method returns a list of *row* objects rather than a list of tuples. Adding a conversion of Agg_output from rows to tuples would allow the `DataFrame` method to do what you want. But why bother with the cursor at all? Just have pandas create the dataframe directly from the query:

```
df = pd.read_sql(Agg,conn)
```